# How do I add the DuckDuckGo .onion version to the Tor Browser search providers?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, onion-services

By default, DuckDuckGo is included in TBB's default list of search providers in the search bar. But it is only their clearnet site (duckduckgo.com), and not their hidden service version, https://duckduckgogg42xjoc72x3sjasowoarfbgcmvfimaftt6twagswzczad.onion.

There is no page or add-on offered by DuckDuckGo to install that includes the .onion URL being added to the search providers - only all their .com versions.

How can I easily add my own custom search provider with the DDG .onion url to Firefox?

Comment: You can get DuckDuckGoOnion Lite and DuckDuckGoOnion HTML from https://ddg-nojs.codeberg.page without downloading any plugins. Both are non-JS versions of DuckDuckGoOnion. Source code: https://codeberg.org/ddg-nojs/pages

Answer (score 11):

**Instructions:**

- Download an existing 'opensearch' XML file for one of the DuckDuckGo provider add-ons, such as the 'Lite' version (or the 'html' version which is also non-JS by default): **https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-lite/** or **https:// addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/duckduckgo-html/**. Do it by right-clicking on the 'Download Now' button on the add-on page and 'save link as' to save the .xml to your computer.
- Modify the XML on your computer to replace all instances of `duckduckgo.com` with `3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion`. For extra security and privacy, double check that https is included in the url strings - HTTPS works on .onion urls also.
- In the `<ShortName>` line, modify the name if you want to differentiate it from the existing one or just make it clear to yourself it's the Tor DDG. e.g.: `<ShortName>DuckDuckGo Lite Tor</ShortName>`.
- If you want family filter censoring turned off (or apply any other cookie-free settings by going to https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/settings with JavaScript on and clicking on 'Show Bookmarklet and Settings Data' to get the relevant parameter), put the following line above the existing  tag line: `<Param name="kp" value="-1"/>`.
- Now upload the XML file to a temporary file sharing service that can provide a direct http link of your modified XML file. E.g.: **https://gist.github.com** and it's **Raw**-Link.
- Find a 'HTML sandbox' site that provides a template for a browser-readable HTML page (a great one that requires no JS and is on HTTPS is https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/html/testbed.html), and put in the `<head>` section this tag: `<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="DuckDuckGo Lite Tor" href="https://direct-link-to-your-modified-xml-file.xml">`
- Load the html sandbox code, and a blank page will be the result (but code obviously in the source). On that page, the  tag tells Firefox that a custom search engine is to be found on this page! Go to the search bar and use the drop-down arrow on the left, and you'll see 'Add "DuckDuckGo Lite Tor". Do it and you can now search from the Firefox bar with Tor hidden service anonymity, forever!
- FYI, the info on adding the  tag was found at: **https:// developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Creating_OpenSearch_plugins_for_Firefox**

Interestingly, this method works for adding ANY custom search engine XML to Firefox in general, which I have also been trying to know how to do (without editing tedious XML/json files in the profile folder and having to restart Firefox, yuck) for years and years, and now I know, boo-ya!

Of course, edit the title or version of DDG as you see fit, my guide is merely a template.

Answer (score 3):

I've followed docksmouth and antiplex's good guide above. You can now install directly from the link below, my source code is on Github.

Go to in Tor Browser http://www.andrewparadi.com/torduckgo/

Source Code: https://github.com/andrewparadi/torduckgo

Comment: The first link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

There are addons for that here.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ddg-onion/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ddg-onion-lite/